# What's the difference between these two Perl snippets?

Tags: perl, heredoc

```
print <<EOF
stuff
EOF
;


print <<EOF;
stuff
EOF
```

Why would you use one over the other?

Comment: I like the first one for being a little bit kinder to the emacs indentation engine.

Comment: I think this is an honest enough question, not subjective/argumentative.

Comment: As always, **TIMTOWTDI** :-) .

Comment: @Zaid: Indeed.  I'm not a Perl programmer, and even someone who was might not be intimately familiar with heredocs.  It's not obvious that these two snippets do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those two examples amount to the same thing behaviourally, but consider if you wanted to do something else after printing that block:

```
print <<EOF
stuff
EOF
. "more text here";
```

...or maybe you need to test the result of the operation:

```
print $unstable_filehandle <<EOF
stuff
EOF
or warn "That filehandle finally disappeared: $!";
```

These examples are contrived, but you can see how sometimes it can be useful to be flexible about what code comes after the block of text.

Answer (score 9):

As [tchrist points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015984/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-perl-snippets/4017872#4017872), one thing that most people neglect is that the heredoc operator takes *arbitrary Perl code* after the termination code.

This means that you can do (arguably) more natural looking manipulation, such as:

```
my $obj = Foo::Bar->new(content => <<EOP)->do_stuff->sprint();
    This is my content
    It's from a heredoc.
EOP
```

One consequence is that you can also stack them *much* more readably (in my opinion ;) than "unstacked":

```
-- stacked_heredoc.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print join(<<JOINER, split("\n", <<SOURCE));

------------------------------
JOINER
This is my text
this is my other text
a third line will get divided!
SOURCE
```

verses an unstacked heredoc...

```
-- unstacked_heredoc.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $joiner = <<JOINER

------------------------------
JOINER
;

my $source = <<SOURCE
This is my text
this is my other text
a third line will get divided!
SOURCE
;

print join($joiner, split("\n", $source));
```

Answer (score 4):

You should treat heredoc tokens exactly like the string literals that they are.  Do not delay further punctuation or syntax until after their contents.  That's misleading and error-prone.  Here are ten examples all taken from real code:

1. `($is_a_valid_rfc_822_addr = <<'EOSCARY') =~ s/\n//g;`
2. `$eval = (($Preamble=<<'END1') . $userstuff . <<'END2');`
3. `for my $line (<<"End_of_Property_List" =~ m{ \S .* \S }gx) {`
4. `$cases .= <<"EDQ" if $timeout;`
5. `($is_a_valid_rfc_822_addr = <<'EOSCARY') =~ s/\n//g;`
6. `eval (($Preamble=<<'END1') . $_[0] . <<'END2');`
7. `@changes = split("\n", <<"EOCHANGES");`
8. `$change .= sprintf(<<"EOP", $in, $out, $in, $out);`
9. `eval "{ package $package; " . <<'EOF' . "}";`
10. `push @args, dequeue('|Q|', <<'END_OF_ASTRAL_MATCH') if $Opt{astral};`

See how that works?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, *Perl Best Practices* recommends:

```
print <<'EOF';
stuff
EOF
```

Comment: Not the same thing. The single quotes suppress interpolation. The equivalent for the question would be with double quotes.

Comment: @igelkott: and pbp recommends single quotes where there isn't actually any interpolation :)

Comment: There's no interpolation happening in the OP, though.

Comment: Perhaps update/expand your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

[Randal Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randal_L._Schwartz) has a [great article on *here* documents](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col12.html).

There are several things to remember about *here* documents:

1. The `;` in Perl is the statement terminator and is required for all Perl statements (with some exceptions) including *here* documents strings;
2. The *here* document is a funny looking statement that is really just a big string;
3. There must be a terminating CR to a *here* document (unlike most other Perl statements);
4. You can have arbitrary Perl code either immediately after the opening tag or after the closing tag. If after the closing tag, it must be on a separate line. In either case, the code operates on the text of the here string;
5. The quotes you use on the tags affect the string. Double quotes are like double quote strings in Perl, single quotes do not interpolate, back quotes get passed to the shell. No quotes are equivalent to double quotes;
6. [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), but some are forms are hard to read;
7. Quoting from `perldoc -q "HERE documents"` (and [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-don%27t-my-%3c%3cHERE-documents-work%3f)):

**There must be no space after the << part.**

**There (probably) should be a semicolon at the end [of the `<<` part].**

**You can’t (easily) have any space in front of the tag.**

The two forms you have are functionally equivalent. Just as `{ ... } if (blah blah)` is the same as `if (blah blah) { ... }`. While these two statements are functionally equivalent, they "read" differently.

Each of these is equivalent and valid Perl *here* documents:

```
my %data = <<END
fred: Fred Flintstone
barney: Barney Rubble
betty: Betty Rubble
wilma: Wilma Flintstone
END
 =~ /(\w+): (.*)/g;
```

and

```
my %data = <<END =~ /(\w+): (.*)/g;
fred: Fred Flintstone
barney: Barney Rubble
betty: Betty Rubble
wilma: Wilma Flintstone
END

# You must have a CR after the "END". Can't be EOF...
```

Both set the `%data` hash to `first=>"full name"` for the Flintstones. Which would you rather see in code coming to you?

Note the second form is one where there is a gotcha: There needs to be text or whitespace after the terminating mark or you may get `Can't find string terminator "END" anywhere before EOF`. I think that is why you see the lone `;` on some people's *here* docs.

IMHO, the `;` belongs after the first instance of the *here* doc tag or the code that follows it. It is harder to read if it is after the closing tag. *Unless* the closing tag is in a form similar to a statement modifier or a warning or *die* logic. That is just my personal style guide.